# Python with pandas and json: How to read nested field

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, large-files

Hello i'm having this problem with pandas where i can't access the field "name" in this nested json field. 
The json itself it's something like

```
 {x:value,y:value,z:value,user:{name:value, id:value ecc...} }
```

the code is this:

```
iteratore=pandas.read_json("C:/path/twitter_dataset_0.json",lines=True, chunksize=100)
for x in iteratore:
    print(x.user.get("name"))
```

this prints me "none",
if i print only `x.user` it gives me back all the fields, if i go for `x.user.name` the ide gives me error, if i go with `items or values` it returns the memory where the data is stored. 
ps i need to use chunksize beacuse is a 3.x gb of file.

Can someone help me to access that specific field?

Edit, my problem is always the same

this is my new code

```
for x in iteratore:
z = x.to_dict() # json_normalize needs a dict, but x is a panda.dataframe, so i needed to convert it in a dict and then pass to json_normaliz
y = pandas.json_normalize(z)
print(y.get("user"))
```

but this is my new error and i do not know how to fix this, my google search was useless.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Utente/PycharmProjects/tesiTwitter/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    y=pandas.json_normalize(z)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\PycharmProjects\tesiTwitter\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 282, in _json_normalize
    data = nested_to_record(data, sep=sep, max_level=max_level)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\PycharmProjects\tesiTwitter\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 106, in nested_to_record
    new_d.update(nested_to_record(v, newkey, sep, level + 1, max_level))
  File "C:\Users\Utente\PycharmProjects\tesiTwitter\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 101, in nested_to_record
    v = new_d.pop(k)
KeyError: '0'
```

Comment: Hello use json library id pretty quick, try this if it doesn't work let me know.

`for x in iteratore['user']:` 

   `print(x['name'])`

Comment: Notice that you can load json data using `with open("C:/path/twitter_dataset_0.json") as f:
  iteratore = json.load(f)`

Comment: `import json`.  ....

Comment: have you tried using this yet? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: 1TypeError: 'JsonReader' object is not subscriptable when working with "iteratore["user"]"

2 I have this large file with more than 1 single json object i should not be able to use json.load

3AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values' i can't normalize it

Comment: @gold_cy ok i've been working with your solution since my last update and i'm getting close, i'm going to update my code above, but i have another error with json normalize.